# Custom UserControl binding in a Silverlight DataGrid template

Tags: silverlight, data-binding

I've been struggling with a solution to a problem. 
I wanted to have the ability to enter a date AND a time and bind them to a single DateTime object in my ViewModel. 
 
I managed to create a custom control that combines a DatePicker and TimeUpDown control. I explained the implementation with code on [my blog](http://www.ronaldrosier.net/Blog/2012/05/04/a_custom_datetimepicker_usercontrol_in_silverlight_5). 

Although, this solution works perfect if the usercontrol is just on my page, the initial thought was to add it to the CellEditingTemplate of a DataGrid. 
During debugging I found out that when leaving the DatePicker or TimeUpDown controls in the template, the property change events are not triggered at all. (could it be some event bubbling issue?).

I really appreciate any ideas around the issue.